# Vue3 - Define / Infer component props based on child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to do a really simple thing but it seems impossible.

My component is the following :

```js
<template>
  <v-autocomplete label="Fournisseur"
    :items="entities"
    item-title="label"
    item-value="id" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";

import { useSuppliers } from "@/services";
import { VAutocomplete } from "vuetify/components";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { entities, fetching, getMany } = useSuppliers();

    onMounted(getMany);

    return {
      entities,
      fetching
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

It's working great and if I put some props on the composent using it, it will works but I don't have any intellisense as the props of my component are not inferred from the VAutocomplete. And vuetify doesn't provide the Props definition of the VAutocomplete.

Is there any way to do something like that :

```js
<template>
  <v-autocomplete label="Fournisseur"
    :items="entities"
    item-title="label"
    item-value="id" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";

import { useSuppliers } from "@/services";
import { VAutocomplete } from "vuetify/components";

export default defineComponent({
  props: VAutocomplete.props, // <-- tell vue that this component has the same prop as VAutocomplete
                              // and maybe tweak it to remove items, item-title and item-value
  setup() {
    const { entities, fetching, getMany } = useSuppliers();

    onMounted(getMany);

    return {
      entities,
      fetching
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

I actually managed to get a solution working with `extends: VAutocomplete` but I'm quite sure this is not the solution for my need. I also tried `defineComponent<VAutocomplete['$props']>` but then it doesn't care of the return of the setup method and I'm not able to use `entities` in the template anymore.

The code is working without any issue, I just want to have some intellisense to help user using this component. And copying all the props defined in VAutocomplete is not actually a way to answer the question as there is a ton of props and it would not update automatically with the library.